# bootstrap columns - page or containers?

Tags: python, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar and main content, however, inside my main content i want to have 3 rows. The top row, will span the whole main content. The middle row has 3 columns equally spaced spanning the main content. The bottom row will have 2 equally spaced.

if my layout of content is

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-1 sidebar">  
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-11 main-content">  
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my css has these spanning the height of 100% of the viewport, so inside the content for my rows i tried -
1. nesting another .container-fluid inside of the main-content  and then do a new row for each the top, middle, and bottom row? 
From my attempts, this did not work I believe due to me trying to nest a container inside another container. If I'm wrong and you can nest a container inside of another, does that container inside .main-content have 12 new columns? Or am i working off of the 11 columns the .main-content is already using?

My other attempt was -
2. going straight to a row (not nesting in another .container. But when i did this, i could not get the row to span the whole .main-content (even using the class="col-md-11"). so my middle row (second row which i wanted to be under the top row) was to the right of my first row. I tried adding .main-content {display: block} to make the rows on top of each other but this did not work either.

Did i approach this wrong? Should I not put the .sidebar and .main-content into the same .container-fluid?

Comment: It's hard to picture. Can you a more complete example with the main content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 sidebar"></div>
      <div class="col-md-11 main-content">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```